# How to refactor an API

Tags: python, api, refactoring

How do you deal with APIs that should be refactored, while not breaking the clients that use the API?

One possible solution I came across: recording refactors to the API, providing the recording to clients of the API which can then apply the refactors to their code:
https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/dig/papers/Thesis.pdf

Does such a thing exist for Python? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You could always provide a bridging layer which looks exactly like the old api, but calls on new functionality where you've made breaking changes. That way old clients can talk to your compatibility api, while new clients may use your new and improved layer.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple, at least in theory — don't ever remove anything, deprecate old stuff instead, while adding new, improved stuff. Don't remove functionality exposed by the deprecated APIs, or emulate it.

Whether your deprecation period (after which you actually remove deprecated stuff) should be short, long or infinite, depends on what the API is, and how many people are using it. If you're using meaningful version numbers, then the rule of thumb is to never break API, unless a major version number changes.

Answer (score 1):

Check Adapter, Decorator and Facade patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There are safe refactorings you can make to an API - introduce parameter, rename, encapsulate parameters.  But with a whole scale refactoring there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Either you preserve the old API for legacy clients (mostly this is an problem in being organized, as other have pointed out) or you actively propagate required changes back to the clients, by hand or by automated means.  You can only do the latter if you have control of all the code that makes calls on the API.

Danny Dig's thesis talks about automated means for doing this.  To do it in general, for each API change you need to apply determine corresponding code changes to client code. Essentially you need a source-to-source program transformation system to apply such changes.

You can see a pretty spectacular version  (aw, shucks) of this in an conversion of C++ code from a legacy OS to CORBA.   In this case, CORBA insists that components have a certain API.  The legacy OS did, too, and the old component used that API.  So what was required to determine the changes to shape legacy APIs into CORBA APIs and apply them across a big code base.  You can read about this at [Akers, R., Baxter, I., Mehlich, M. , Ellis, B. , Luecke, K., Case Study: Re-engineering C++ Component Models Via Automatic Program Transformation, Information & Software Technology 49(3):275-291 2007.](http://www.mendeley.com/research/case-study-reengineering-c-component-models-via-automatic-program-transformation/).

The good news is that we (the community) kind of undestand what to do.  The not so good news is the technology isn't off-the-shelf, pushbutton yet.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mithon @DaeMoohn to make version 1 to be an adpater of version 2

Another option is: don't know in Python, but in Java you can create packages for new versions:

```
package your.api;

interface AAA{
 //old api
}
```

now, you need to create a version 2:

```
package you.api.v2;

interface AAA{
 //new api
}
```